# how i send notification email to reference email when user register in laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-8

i am trying to send an notification custom email to reference email when user register

using Mail Inception in Laravel 8

i don't need to send email to user himself i want to send that email to email reference which is user will write it in registration field

**CreateNewUser Default Controller from Laravel**

```
<?php

namespace App\Actions\Fortify;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\CreatesNewUsers;
use Laravel\Jetstream\Jetstream;
use Carbon\Carbon;


use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use App\Mail\RefMail;


class CreateNewUser implements CreatesNewUsers
{  
    use PasswordValidationRules;

    /**
     * Validate and create a newly registered user.
     *
     * @param  array  $input
     * @return \App\Models\User
     */
    public function create(array $input)
    {   $massage = ['tc_no_pasaport_no.unique'=> 'Sorry, internal error .',
        'phone.unique'=>'Sorry, internal error .' ];
        
       Validator::make($input, [
            'phone' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255','unique:users'],

            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            
            'tc_no_pasaport_no' => ['required','max:11','unique:users'],
            'place_of_birth' => ['required'],
            'date_of_birth' => ['required'],
            'educational_status' => ['required','string'],
            'school_department' => ['required'],
            'address' => ['required'],
           



            'password' => $this->passwordRules(),
            'terms' => Jetstream::hasTermsAndPrivacyPolicyFeature() ? ['required', 'accepted'] : '',
        ],$massage)->validate();

        $users = User::where('email', '=', $input['email'])->first();
            if ($users === null) {
            return User::create([

            'name' => $input['name'],
            'email' => $input['email'],
            'phone' => $input['phone'],

            'password' => Hash::make($input['password']),
            'membership_status' =>'pasif',
            'membership_type' =>'standard',
            'last_activation_date' =>  Carbon::now(),
            'membership_end_date' =>  Carbon::now(),     
            'temporary_id' => random_int(1000000, 9999999),
            'tc_no_pasaport_no' => $input['tc_no_pasaport_no'],
            'place_of_birth' => $input['place_of_birth'],
            'date_of_birth' => $input['date_of_birth'],
            'educational_status' => $input['educational_status'],
            'school_department' => $input['school_department'],
            'Institution_and_unit' => $input['Institution_and_unit'],
            'address' => $input['address'],
            'referance_email' => $input['referance_email'],
            'letter_of_Intent'=>$input['letter_of_Intent'],
            'created_at' => Carbon::now(),


        ]);}
            

        $data = [
            'name' => $input->name,
            'referance_email' => $input->referance_email,
        ];

        Mail::to($input->referance_email)->send(new RefMail ($data));

    }
}
```

**RefMail code**

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class RefMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $data;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {

        $this->data = $data;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {   $sendemail =$this->data;
        return $this->from('info@geleceginbilimi.com')->view('mail.ref_mail',compact('sendemail'))->subject('confirm recommended email');
    }
}
```

**ref_mail.blade.php**

```
 <h1>{{$sendemail->name}}</h1>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First replace `OrderMail` with `RefMail`

```
Mail::to($input->referance_email)->send(new RefMail($data));
```

Second add `$data` variable to the constructor of `RefMail` Class:

```
public function __construct($data)
{

    $this->data = $data;
}
```

Third :

```
<h1>{{$sendemail['name']}}</h1>
```

For more : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail#writing-mailables

Comment: i have used that alink you send it to me but i couldn't know how to pass the reference email to MailController in the same time when user register and send email to reference email

Comment: pass two arguements to **public function __construct($data, $email)** declare another public variable that stores email addresses of references and make that public $email variable as array so that you can send email to multiple references that your user gives